# Will Google index pages that are 95% the same?

Tags: seo, google-search, duplicate-content, search-results

We have a website with more than 200 pages. All 200 pages URLs will be shown like these sample URLs:

```
www.example.com/india/population/
www.example.com/newzealand/population/
www.example.com/namibia/population/
```

95% of the main & inner content of the all pages will be same. The URL, page title, h1 heading tag and population are different in all 200 pages. But the remaining 95% of the content is the same. Is that any problem?

Does Google consider these kind of pages are duplicate? I am confused. Because, all of the pages have 95% same content, main contents (5%) are different only. Is google penalize these kind of sites in SERP?

These below mentioned keywords will be different in all 200 pages.

- URL (`www.example.com/newzealand/population/`)
- Page title (New Zealand Population Information)
- H1 heading tag (New Zealand Population)
- Population number (45,067,056) in every page

Comment: This isn't necessarily duplicate content.  I would call this "thin content."  See also: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to over-worry. In my experience, some sites have almost 98% same contents of pages, different keywords. These sites gets top ranking in SERPs. Instead your site ranking time can be somewhat long than usual.